# OpenLayers 3 Layer Visibility Checkbox

Tags: openlayers, layers

[This JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joshuadickerson92/nhubbL7m/3/) example currently changes the visibility of a layer using two individual buttons.

However, i want to change this to just one check-box, the check-box in this case has been styled by Bootstrap Check-box.What would be the most simple method to bind the set.visibility command to this?

Edit: I have also tried to do this with a `function toggleOSM()`linked the `onClick` of the check-box as per [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joshuadickerson92/nhubbL7m/4/) but it doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `onSwitchChange` option of *bootstrapSwitch*:

```
$("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch({
    onSwitchChange: function (event, state) {
        rasterLayer.setVisible(state)
    }
});
```